# Python tkinter, canvas don't show

Tags: python, tkinter

The canvas dosen't work for me with tkinter, i got menu working, also toplevel windows but not canvas. Here is my example:

```
class Interface(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.__loadSettings()
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.m=Menu(self)
        menu = Menu(self.m, tearoff=0)
        self.m.add_cascade(label="File", menu=menu)
        menu.add_command(label="New", command=self.__newGame)
        menu = Menu(self.m, tearoff=0)
        self.m.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=menu)
        menu.add_command(label="Settings", command=self.__settings)
        self.master.config(menu=self.m)
        self.canvas= Canvas(self,height=500, width=500)
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,100,400,400, fill="blue")

root = Tk()
ui = Interface(root)
ui.mainloop()
```

The windows and menu works, but not the canvas.

Comment: this code doesn't work as posted. People will be more able to help you if you post actual working code. The above code is missing an import statement, and also references a couple of class methods that don't exist. Help us to help you by posting working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you put the canvas in a frame (an instance of `Interface`) but you never make this frame visible. Since this frame is designed to be the whole UI (I'm assuming), you can do this:

```
root = Tk()
ui = Interface(root)
ui.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
ui.mainloop()
```

Notice that I call `pack` on the `ui` object.

That only solves half of the problem. The second problem is that you aren't making the canvas visible in its parent. You can use `pack`, `grid` or `place` for that. Here I use `pack`:

```
self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

You seem to have a third problem as well -- you're creating a menu but you aren't causing it to be visible, either. In the case of a menubar, you usually give it as the value of the `menu` attribute of a root window. In your case you might want to do something like this:

```
self.master.configure(menu=self.m)
```